# What should be the dimension of images for a website?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive

I have images given to me but they are too big to fit in my static website.
How can i optimize these images? What is optimum height and width for the website?

Comment: If you are using Twitter-Bootstrap you can simply add `.img-responsive` to your `<img/>` tag.

Comment: The answer to this question very much depends on the layout of your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The optimum size for the website depends on the device that you are going to 
   view the website with(eg: Desktop, mobile).
2. When selecting the width of the page make sure the viewer does not have to 
   scroll horizontally(width should fit the screen). Height should depend on the 
   contents in the website(can be allowed to scroll vertically).
3. The best way is to use bootstrap to make the page responsive so that the page 
   will adjust itself to meet the screen dimensions. Use the following link to use 
   bootstrap in your page. http://getbootstrap.com/